# Various files to various destination while RPM Generation using rpm plugin in gradle

Tags: gradle, rpm

I am writing a gradle code using `Gradle-ospackage RPM Plugin` to generate RPM. I am able to generate RPM. My requirement is that, while generating the RPM, specific files should be moved to different location.
For Example I have below structure,

```
           |--SOURCES
              --Properties
                --a.property
                --b.property
                --c.property
              --configs
                --conf.xml
                --cache.xml
              --war
                --test.war
              --testng.java
              --val.java
              ...
              ...
           |--SPECS
           |--RPMS
           |--SRPMS
```

In the above example, when generating rpm, `*.properties`,`*.war` and `conf.xml` should be moved to some other path like `/modules/properties/`,`/modules/binaries/` and `/modules/conf/`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nebula-ospackage`plugin makes use of Gradle `Copy Spec` feature, which allows you to configure the "mappings" between sources directory structure and target rpm content layout, using `from` and `into` clauses. You can find several examples in the plugin documentation [here](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/Usage-Example) and [here](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/RPM-Plugin#copy-spec).

In you example, you could have something like below

```
ospackage{
    // (...)

    into("/modules"){ 
        into ("properties"){
            from ("/SOURCES/Properties") // you could add some filtering                
        }
        into ("binaries"){
            from ("/SOURCES/war")
        }
        into ("conf"){
            from ("/SOURCES/configs")
        }                   
        // EDIT : include all .java source files
        into ("sources"){
            from ("/SOURCES") {
                 include "**/*.java"
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @M.Ricciuti  This could work from me. and my issue is that while packaging rpm, only these files are getting included in rpm leaving remaining files unincluded(ie., `testng.java,val.java....`)  . Is there any option  to include remaining all files to other location without mentioning specific source file names.

Comment: I'm not aware of an option to "include all remaining (not yet included) files", but an easy way is to use `include` in the `from` clause, to fetch all java source files. See my updated answer